# Entity Framework foreign key problems on Oracle - code-first

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I have the following mapping using code-first:

```
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Entity Framework Dc.Dc database table object representation
    /// </summary>
    [Table("DCDC", Schema = "MZMESDB")]
    public class EfDcDc
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Element ID
        /// </summary>
        [Column("ID")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Name of DC
        /// </summary>
        [Column("NAME")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// DC Description
        /// </summary>
        [Column("DESCRIPTION")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Foreign Key
        /// </summary>
        public virtual EfSystemDataModule Module { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Name of module
        /// </summary>
        [Column("ENABLED")]
        public string Enabled { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and

```
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Entity Framework SystemData.Module database table object representation
    /// </summary>
    [Table("SYSTEMDATAMODULE", Schema = "MZMESDB")]
    public class EfSystemDataModule
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Element ID
        /// </summary>
        [Column("ID")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Name of module
        /// </summary>
        [Column("NAME")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// If the module is installed. Char because Oracle does not support boolean
        /// </summary>
        [Column("INSTALLED")]
        public char Installed { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// If the module is enabled. Char because Oracle does not support boolean
        /// </summary>
        [Column("ENABLED")]
        public char Enabled { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Oracle tables has a foreign key:

```
CREATE TABLE "MZMESDB"."DCDC" ( 
                                "ID" INTEGER NOT NULL , 
                            "NAME" VARCHAR2(64) NOT NULL , 
                            "DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR(256),
                            "MODULE_ID" INTEGER NOT NULL,
                            "MODULE_NAME" VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
                            "ENABLED" CHAR NOT NULL, 
                            PRIMARY KEY ("ID") VALIDATE,
                            FOREIGN KEY (MODULE_ID, MODULE_NAME) REFERENCES SYSTEMDATAMODULE(ID, NAME)
```

No problems at compilation, but at rutime when I issue:

```
MzDbContext dbContext = new MzDbContext();
            EfDcDc configuredDC = new EfDcDc();

            try
            {
                configuredDC = dbContext.efDcDc.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Name == "COMMON_NAME");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error reading from database. Message: " + e.Message.ToString());
                return false;
            }
```

I get the following error from Oracle EF driver:

```
ORA-00904: \"Extent1\"."\"Module_Id\":Invalid identifier.
```

I just wanna check if the DcDc element exists in the database to later take its data for processing. what am I doing wrong ?

Rds

Answer (score 1):

This is usually from an invalid column name.  In Oracle, everything is in upper case for the column names.  Where is the mixed case Module_Id coming from?  I only see the ID used in your code.

Comment: You may need to look at the query generated.  Take a look at http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/faq.html#q56

Comment: No idea where the mixed case Module_Id is coming from. I took the SQL code from dbContext and injected at SQLPLUS. Just adjusting this Module_Id case and everything goes well with the select statement. Definitely this is the problem, but no idea how to fix it...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to EF internal mechanism that is not uppercasing some internal names...

So, Module_Id does not exist in Oracle, as the table fields are MODEL_ID. I´m still working around on this...

Comment: To update I did not solved that for now. I´ve changed from code first to model first and my problem disappeared. Of course I have now new problems like changing the connection string on the fly, but this let me continue focused on the application development itself.